# Only permit most recent async method invocation

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, task, c#-5.0

I call an async method every time a textbox registers a textchange event. This async method performs a task on the text in the textbox. The problem is that when the user is typing fast a more recent async method may finish before async methods called before it.

What I need to do is destroy all previous async method calls and only continue invocation with the most recent. How do I achieve this?

Comment: or use a timer to wait until a long enough pause in typing....

Comment: What you need are Reactive Extensions (Rx): http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/gg577609.aspx

Comment: Here is exactly what you need, called Throttle: http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any third party libraries, there are two things you can do.

The first is to add a delay before taking action, so in your async method that you start when a change happens:

```
await Task.Delay(1000); // Wait a second before getting into the work.
```

The second is to keep a hold of a reference to the Task you created on change.  Then when a change happens again, you can await the original task to let it complete before starting off a new one, or if you prefer, pass it a CancellationToken when you create it so that you can cancel that token and start the new task immediately.

Ultimately, it comes down to how important it is that one doesn't outrun the other.  If its critical, await the original Task, even in the situation where you cancel it.  If it doesn't matter *too* much, then just cancel it and let it wind down in its own time.

And, of course, if you don't need it to do anything in the UI thread, remember to add .ConfigureAwait(false) whereever you await.